# Null when loading serialized object from file

Tags: java, serializable

I am trying to save a GameSave object into a file and load it from there. GameSave (same for the referenced objects) implements Serializable. The loaded object appears to be null. I do not get any error.
I have been trying to solve this problem for over a week with no result.

GameSave class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Stores all data of a game. Wraps game data like previous moves.
 */
public class GameSave implements Serializable {

    private Board board;
    private Color currentColor;

    public GameSave() {
        this.board = new Board();
        this.currentColor = Color.WHITE;
    }
}
```

Class to save the object:

```
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Backend to story game saves to a file backend
 */
public class FileBackendText implements Backend {
    /**
     * Load a game from the given save name
     *
     * @param saveName the name of the save
     * @return a {@link GameSave} instance; null if no save could be found
     */
    @Override
    public GameSave loadGame(String saveName) {

        createDirectories();

        GameSave gameSave;
        File file = new File("/saves/"+saveName+".ser");

        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            gameSave = (GameSave) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Loaded: " + gameSave);

        return gameSave; //TODO: Load from file backend
    }

    /**
     * Creates the save data directories
     */
    private void createDirectories() {
        if(new File("/saves").mkdirs())
            System.out.println("Created save directories!");
    }

    /**
     * Save a {@link GameSave} instance to the backend
     *
     * @param gameSave  the name of the save
     * @param saveName  the game data to be stored
     * @param overwrite overwrite old data if given
     * @return was save successful. Not successful if file has to be overwritten and overwrite parameter is false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean saveGame(GameSave gameSave, String saveName, boolean overwrite) {

        createDirectories();

        File file = new File("/saves/"+saveName+".ser");

        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if(file.exists() && !overwrite)
            return false;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut =
                    new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(gameSave);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Game data saved in /saves/%s.ser\n",saveName);
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true; //TODO: save to file backend
    }
}
```

So I actually want to have a game save object upon calling the load method, but get null.

Comment: Do Board and Color also implement Serializable?

Comment: @racraman: Not the issue since we already know that `java.awt.Color` implements Serializable, and if Board did not implement this, then the OP's problem would be completely different as he'd be dealing with a thrown NotSerializableException, not failure to create the reference. To the OP, the code you've posted above works, suggesting that the problem lies elsewhere.